# error "The 'WebBluetooth' feature is currently enabled in limited trials..."

Tags: google-chrome, ionic-framework, console.log

When I use `ionic serve` to test my ionic app in browser, I get this error:

> The 'WebBluetooth' feature is currently enabled in limited trials. Please see [Phosphor console URL] for information on enabling a trial for your site.

Here's a snap shot of the `console`:

[image: console snap]

Why do I get this error? Will that affect anything? Of course it's always annoying to see any red text lines in my console. How do I solve it?

It's just a blank app initialized using `ionic start newApp blank`.

I am using google Chrome browser: `Version 50.0.2661.26 beta-m (64-bit)`.